# Can I set the ASP.NET Version used by the Visual Studio ASP.NET Development Server?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to debug a problem which shows up under IIS7 using an application pool configured for .NET 4.  My Visual Studio ASP.NET Development Server says it is using 2.0.50727.5456.

[image: ASP.NET Development Server details dialog]

I'd like to debug this out of VS so I'd like the .NET versions to match.  I've found info on setting ports but there was no version setting nearby.  And I couldn't find anything under the the *Website.ASP Configuration* menu item in VS either.

Is there any way to configure the ASP.NET Development Server's .NET version?

Comment: what is your project built with?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Pro in C# as a Website project.  My dev box is a Win7 Pro 64 bit system current with its windows updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `targetFramework` attribute of your [compilation element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx) in your `web.config`. If it's missing, add the attribute, and try setting it to `4.0`.

If you're using a web application project (not a web site), try checking the project settings and look for Target Framework.

Comment: I'm using a website project.  Its _Property Pages.Build.Target Framework_ is set to .NET Framework 3.5.  There wasn't a web.config `compilation.targetFramework` attribute.  Adding one `=v4.0` gives a compiler warning that the attribute is not allowed.

Comment: Following the warnings I removed the web.config `compilation.targetFramework` entry and set _Property Pages.Build.Target Framework_ to 4.  Running the website now shows .NET 4 in the Development Server details.  Thanks for the pointers @wsanville

Comment: Are you talking about on right clicking the project => Select properties => Application => Target Framework ?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to make sure you have installed VS 2010 SP1, then install IIS Express which is a stand-alone version of IIS used for development.  This uses the exact same code as is in the full IIS, this way your environment is the same.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/

Comment: I've got IIS7 installed and can run this app under either.  Eventually I'll climb the debugging curve with "real" IIS but I'm familiar with the dev server and wanted to run with it for now.